# React Native WebView HTTPS Urls not loaded in Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, https, webview, ssl-certificate

I'm using react-native-webview which is suggested by React Native documentation. WebView shows white screen when I try to load HTTPS Url in Android. In IoS it works fine. How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try on different URLs?

Comment: Try implementing it using the Native WebView component and see if you experience the same error

Comment: Yes I tried on different urls, many of them are working, but, my url is not working. Btw my url is working in all browsers and it says that url is secure and it has valid ssl certificate. @Naeim

Comment: I've already used Native WebView. nothing changed. @SamuelOmole